# Spring Transactional annotation causes unwanted rollback-only

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

We're using Spring 3.2.0. Our service classes all have *ServiceImpl with @Transactional annotations, eg on bean vatcodeServiceTarget:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly=true)
public VatCodeModel loadBy(String crsname, String crscode, int clientid) {
  ..
}
```

We wrap the ServiceImpl with a TransactionProxyFactoryBean

```
<bean id="vatcodeService" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="target" ref="vatcodeServiceTarget"/>
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and inject the resulting bean into our controllers. If another ServiceImpl needs the 'vatcodeService', we actually inject the 'vatcodeServiceTarget' so the transaction boundaries are discarded.

This approach worked well in Spring 2.0. Now, in Spring 3.2.0, I observe the following effect:

1. A controller calls another ServiceImpl, transactional
2. That other ServiceImpl calls VatcodeServiceImpl#loadBy(). There is no transaction boundary wrapped around the loadBy() call
3. VatcodeServiceImpl#loadBy() fails to load the sought database row and throws a DataNotFoundException
4. The transaction in the other ServiceImpl is now marked rollback-only.

It appears the RuntimeException across the @Transactional boundary is enough to mark the tx rollback-only, even though that specific call was actually not transactional.

Am I configuring something wrong, or is Spring @Transactional aspect behaving unexpectedly here?

Thanks
Simon Niederberger

Comment: Is `VatCodeServiceImpl` in any of the component scan paths?

Comment: @ach: We're not using `context:component-scan` at the time, but `VatCodeServiceImpl` is defined as a bean in the Spring context.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think there is no transaction boundary? You added annotations - spring added aspect which opens transaction and marks it rollbackonly on runtime exceptions. You may throw some checked exception instead of unchecked one if you really don't want to rollback this transaction, but I can't see why would you wanna do this.